# Is it possible to make a boundary box for an object while sculpting?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, objects

I am modelling a statue which will sit on a stand. While I'm modeling, I would like to make it so that I can't sculpt past the surface of this stand:

[image]

I have manipulated the mesh in edit mode so that it's flat against the stand. But the moment I want to sculpt the bottom part further, I risk making the statue go past this stand. Is it possible to make the stand an obstacle/boundary?

Comment: or you could model as usual and later make the bottom flat with scale along z-axis with respect to 3d cursor?

Comment: yep, that's what I do now. I was just wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Aside from correcting in Edit mode, you can lock sculpting by global axes, in this case lock Z axis. Note that lock affect sculpting everywhere so it might be useful only in related area.